# How to switch to the latest release version?

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I'm using the `versions` plugin to update the dependencies to my projects, where the versions are defined in properties, e.g:

```
<properties>
    <version.property>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version.property>
</properties>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
         <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
         <version>${version.property}</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now `versions:update-properties` is doing a good job here, but for one situation. Lets say the `version.property` is set to the latest snapshot version available in my repo: `1.6-SNAPSHOT`.

I would expect from the following command, that the version changes to `1.5`

```
mvn versions:update-properties
```

But it stays on the latest snapshot.. Now what I'm missing here? The docs claims:

> ...executing the `update-properties` goal will update the `version.property` property to the latest common version available in your local repository and all currently active remote repositories

The parameter `allowSnapshots` is false by default. So, whats going on?
Why the version isn't updating to the latest release, which is 1.5? How can I do this?

Comment: This is normal really. `update-properties` can only move the version forward, not backward. More info here: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Right-behaviour-of-versions-update-properties-td5714058.html It sounds like you need to use `versions:use-latest-releases` instead of a property.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this behaviour isn't stated in the docs.